# Chose start position of search

Tags: string, batch-file, find

I'm trying to make a script that first searches after a string then starts a search for a different string on the lines after the first strings position. 
String1 only occurs once but string2 occurs multiple times and its only string2 that occurs after string one I'm in need of.

Clarification:

```
text text text
more text text
text text string2 <-- I don't whant this one
text text text
text text string1 <-- I whant this line
even more text
text string2 text <-- I whant this line
text text text
string2 text text<-- I don't whant this one
```

It has to work even if the file dosen not look like this, another order, more of string2 etc. etc.
Is this possible?

Comment: You'd have to clarify your clarification. What is the formula to determine which strings are wanted? Do you want only the strings you've indicated? What about the other strings like `text`?

Comment: What kind of information do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using PowerShell for this. It'll make things *a lot* easier.

```
$inputfile = 'C:\path\to\input.txt'

$m1 = Select-String string1 $inputfile
$m2 = Select-String string2 $inputfile `
        | ? { $_.LineNumber -gt $m1.LineNumber } `
        | select -First 1

$m1.Line
$m2.Line
```

Comment: That depends on your operating system. On halfway recent systems PowerShell is preinstalled (v1 on Vista/Server 2008, v2 on 7/Server 2008 R2, v3 on 8/Server 2012). There's an [upgrade](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929) that will add PowerShell v2 to XP/Server 2003. More recent OS versions can be [upgraded](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) to v3.

Comment: So can I just  use this frame in a ordinary batch file?

Comment: No. The above is PowerShell code and will not work in a batch script. You could run a PowerShell script from a batch file via `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"`, but then you could just as well run it directly.

Comment: So the file extension for powershell is .ps1 ?

Comment: Good! I try it out when i have time!

Comment: Worked really well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming none of your lines start with a : (that limitation can be fixed with extra code)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=yourfile.txt"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (type "%file%"^|'find "string1"') do (
  set /a start=%%A
  echo(%%B
  goto :getString2
)
:getString2
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('type "%file%"^|find "string2"') do (
  if %%A gtr %start% echo(%%B
)
```

Comment: No, they don't would that be favorable?

Comment: @user2583237 - If none of the lines start with `:` then the above code should work perfectly. In other words, any leading `:` will be stripped from each line. The code can be modified to preserve leading `:`, but that is not necessary because you say there aren't any leading `:`.